# python3 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an error when I try to add bottom to a linkList from a python list
My code is:

def Eight():

```
aList = [7,12,14,5,9,6]
def createList(pythonList,linkList = None):
    for i in pythonList:
        linkList = addBottom(linkList,i)
    return linkList
def addBottom(aList,value):
    ptr = aList
    if ptr == None:
        return {'data':value,'next':None}
    while ptr != None:
        ptr = ptr['next']
    ptr['next'] = {'data':value,'next':None}
    return aList
print(createList(aList))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module> Eight() 
File "C:\Users\17yz77\Downloads\Problem.py", line 164, in Eight 
    print(createList(aList)) 
File "C:\Users\17yz77\Downloads\Problem.py", line 151, in 
    createList linkList = addBottom(linkList,i) 
File "C:\Users\17yz77\Downloads\Problem.py", line 161, in 
    addBottom ptr['next'] = {'data':value,'next':None} 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    Eight()
  File "C:\Users\17yz77\Downloads\Problem.py", line 164, in Eight
    print(createList(aList))
  File "C:\Users\17yz77\Downloads\Problem.py", line 151, in createList
    linkList = addBottom(linkList,i)
  File "C:\Users\17yz77\Downloads\Problem.py", line 161, in addBottom
    ptr['next'] = {'data':value,'next':None}
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Really don't know why can't I say None = addBottom(None,i)

Comment: You can't say that because it doesn't make any sense.  `None` is the special name give to the Python object that has no value.  Assigning the returned value of a function to this special name is meaningless.

Comment: Edit the error message into the posting, not as a comment.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reach the end of the structure, then extend it.  The problem is that your loop runs you off the end.  `None` is a constant; you cannot change its value.  Instead, stop at the last node:

```
while ptr['next'] is not None:
    ptr = ptr['next']

# ptr is now the last node in the sequence.
ptr['next'] = {'data':value,'next':None}
```

Note also that `is` and `is not` are better was to check against `None`.  The reasons for this are available in many other postings.

Comment: We invite you to contribute -- even if we have to wait until you learn enough on some chosen topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ptr != None:
    ptr = ptr['next']
    # !!! At this point in the code, ptr is None !!!
ptr['next'] = {'data':value,'next':None}
```

You can't assign items to `None` since `None` represents nothing.

Comment: OMG thank you so much I don't even know what should I say I just really excited and glad some one do help my code.

Comment: Thank you so much this is my first time ask question, XDDDD

Comment: wait a second, but it's the ptr is node, I will return it back

Comment: that means this function should stop and no more running from this while loop

Comment: the while loop will stop, but not the rest of the function.

Comment: I kind of understand it!!! but how should I fix this problem? Should I say

Comment: while ptr['next']!= None:
            ptr = ptr['next']